# Is it possible to install docker on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows, docker, windows-server-2016

I installed docker on Windows Server 2016 using a blog:

https://knowledge.kofax.com/bundle/TotalAgility_integrationserverinstallguide_TotalAgility_IS_guide/page/All_Shared/guide_installation/t_installdockeronwindows.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=dockerce#windows-server-1

The docker client and server installed, however the service won't start. Event Viewer shows error "docker requires build 17763 or higher" (our 2016 is build 14393).

However, according to google 17763 corresponds to.... Windows 10. What am I supposed to make of this? Is Docker not supported on Windows Server at all, not even 2019/2022?

Comment: Downvoter, care to share your reason for downvoting?

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but did you even google this? https://forums.docker.com/t/unable-to-install-docker-on-windows-server/137284

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1061812/windows-server-2016-standard-cannot-install-docker

Comment: `What am I supposed to make of this?` you need a higher version of Windows.

Comment: My guess would be you installed the Community Edition. The Enterprise Edition supports Windows Server 2016.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1061812/windows-server-2016-standard-cannot-install-docker

Comment: @S.Walker I did. That's how I was able to resolve installation issues and get it installed.

Comment: Do you want to run Windows containers or Linux containers?

Answer (score 1):

If you want docker on Windows server, for running Linux images, the obvious solution is to just install the Hyper-V Role.  Create a VM using your favorite distro, and install docker in there.

If you were set on using 'Docker Desktop', I suspect you are going to be disappointed.

Comment: I would jokingly suggest running Docker on WSL, but there's already a procedure for that too. https://docs.docker.com/desktop/wsl/